# Cannot open more documents if all the others are closed

Tags: macos, ms-office, adobe

My girlfriend experiences the following strange behavior on her MacBook Pro running on Yosemite. It does not happen all the time but when it does, things are always the same:

She closes all the opened documents from apps like ms-word, Adobe Acrobat Reader or Adobe Indesign and then tries to open a new one from the `finder` window. It looks like the document will be opened, but it doesn't.
The app is still running but the file is not opened.
Opening it from the `File` menu still works, though.

When this happens she also cannot close the app neither from the `File` menu nor the `Dock`. She needs to go to `Activity Monitor` and force quit the app.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an option from the dock. Go to System Preferences -> Dock and uncheck the Option **Minimize windows into application icon**.

If you not see the Window you have in every Application the Window menu. Choose from there the Option **Bring all to Front**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the option is already unchecked. We also checked already in the Window menu but no docs are opened so Bring all to front do nothing :(

Comment: Have she experienced this only with the same apps? Some new installations in the past? It sounds to me that the applications freezes and is  an indication that one or more background apps not working together.

Restart the mac and hold the Shift-Key  during startup. This will start into the safe mode (On the top right you get the message if you are in Safe mode). 

The startup is a little slower as normal and flashing screen in normal. Log in and open the Disc Utility app. Check and repair the permission.

Restart in normal mode when done.

Comment: Well, it does it at least with ms-word, Adobe Acrobat Reader or Adobe Indesign. We'll try the safe mode and let you know, thanks!